# Java - How to set my application always run on main screen but not in the second screen?

Tags: java, linux, swing, xorg

I have two screen, main laptop and second monitor. Whenever i launch this application, it runs on my second screen instead of main screen.

How do i tell the application to run only on main screen which is the left one.

Example:

```
screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice[] screenDevices = ge.getScreenDevices();
for (int i = 0; i < screenDevices.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(screenDevices[i].getIDstring());
  DisplayMode dm = screenDevices[i].getDisplayMode();
  int screenWidth = dm.getWidth();
  int screenHeight = dm.getHeight();
  System.out.println("[myResolution]: " + screenWidth + " " + screenHeight);
  screen.width = screenWidth;
  screen.height = screenHeight;
}

Output:
0.0
1024x768
0.1
1024x768
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't the `JFrame.setLocation()` work?
if you are really picky about screens, you can specify where to display your JFrame:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html

The very first paragraph gives an example how to achieve what you want